# Issues with de Sitter Space and Conformal Field Theory

Tags: gravity, conformal-field-theory, ads-cft, holographic-principle, de-sitter-spacetime

As a de Sitter universe is more convenient for cosmology, what are the current issues with a dS/CFT type correspondence? Earlier work by [**Strominger**](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0106113), seemed promising but I haven't heard of additional developments and I was wondering about the challenges facing such a theory.

**Clarification:** Since de Sitter spacetimes are dual to Euclidean conformal field theories, is a dS/CFT correspondence hopeless to reproduce the dynamics of quantum field theories and gravity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that a bulk theory is dual to a field theory on the boundary is really nothing special. Maxwell's equations are dual to the constraint field theory on boundary conditions. The problem is that the field theory is typically some weird composite, for instance a combination of an initial and boundary condition for Maxwell will give $div \vec{B}$ on the initial conditions and the projection of the rest into the boundary.

Similarly, the conformal infinity in AdS is a boundary requiring the specification of boundary conditions in the sense that there is no complete Cauchy surface in the AdS space-time on its own. For details see the following paper and references therein: [Helmut Friedrich (1995), *Einstein equations and conformal structure: Existence of Anti-de Sitter type space-times*](http://pubman.mpdl.mpg.de/pubman/item/escidoc:153123:1/component/escidoc:153122/Einstein.pdf). But the point of AdS is also that the boundary is a really nice place, Minkowski, and there are no weird composites happening so that is why we hear about it much more than of anything else.

Now to dS. dS has a conformal infinity ("boundary"), but to evolve field theories in dS, we do ***not*** need to specify anything there! Actually, dS is the "anti" twin of AdS because dS in some sense needs the conformal infinity and generally far-away data less and less with evolution. Everything gets eventually devoured by the cosmological horizon, trajectories diverge, and matter (any field excitation with time-like/null behaviour) dilutes and stops interacting.

So, from this physical insight, I see very little prospect for a dS/CFT duality in the sense of a bulk-boundary theory. I do not know the work you cite but I would expect that the results for scalar field theory they get is a coincidence or a consequence of well chosen assumptions.

Answer (score 1):

Since I am working on de Sitter, let me also point out another interesting aspect of dS/CFT: entanglement entropy is hard to find. In AdS/CFT, you had two nice proposals for holographic entanglement entropy, namely Ryu-Takayanagi and Hubeny-Rangamani-Takayanagi. The idea for RT was essentially that you took a boundary subregion $A$, and found the minimal spacelike bulk geodesic joining the endpoints of $A$. This was the RT surface $\gamma _{A}$. However, for dS/CFT, you have no spacelike geodesic joining two *unique* boundary points; you have instead a timelike geodesic, due to which the entanglement entropy becomes complex-valued. This is a factor from the non-unitary nature of the dual CFT in dS. This is hard. So, you also don't have those nice and sweet subregion duality and bulk reconstruction aspects that we had from RT in AdS/CFT. This also complicates the usual motivation towards bulk reconstruction, but I think there is a go-around for this. You can do all sorts of things -- like understand $T\overline{T}$-deformations from the boundary to do Cauchy slice holography for dS/CFT, and make sense of canonical asymptotic quantum gravity, which is closely related to this. In the bulk reconstruction sense, you have two dictionaries that are the dS/CFT counterparts to the extrapolate dictionary in AdS/CFT -- the *differentiate* dictionary, as used by Maldacena in his 2002 paper, and the *extrapolate* dictionary, which has not one but *two* conformal weights. Of course, this can be expected from $\mathcal{I}^{+}\to \mathcal{I}^{-}$ extremal surfaces, but this is a complication nonetheless.

Here, it is now worth pointing out that an alternative holography proposal for de Sitter is static patch holography, where you can compute entanglement entropy quite nicely by using covariant bit threads -- see Susskind and Shaghoulian's paper on this. This is nice, because Freedman and Headrick found that the RT formula could be found from a bit threads proposal. Also, static patch is famous for Chandrasekharan, Longo, Pennington and Witten's amazing work on algebra of observables. In fact, here as well you can work with deformations, called $T\overline{T}+\Lambda $ deformations. However, I reserve that dS/CFT is the physically important one, while static patch is the mathematically important description. There are some other descriptions as well (such as introducing a timelike hard-wall in dS), but I reserve that these are not the right descriptions of de Sitter holography.