Why is hyperbolic space needed in AdS / CFT?
Is there a reason why a hyperbolic bulk is needed in AdS/CFT (other than the name suggests it must be an AdS)?
In other words would a flat or positively curved bulk, work with the CFT correspondence? If no why not?

A negative cosmological constant is needed. There is no clean version of holography for flat or de Sitter spacetimes.

The CFT lives on the boundary of the AdS space. Flat or dS spaces don't have a boundary so there's nowhere for the CFT to live.

@JohnRennie - Flat spacetimes most definitely have a boundary - in fact, they have 3 qualitatively different boundaries (${\cal I}^+$, ${\cal I}^-$ and $i^0$). Flat holography can, in principle, be attempted on all or some of them. Previous attempts attempted to mimic AdS/CFT and used $i^0$ as the appropriate boundary, but they all mostly failed. Recent attempts (Celestial Holography and/or Carrollian Holography) use ${\cal I}$ and that seems to have had more success. Nothing has yet come close to what AdS/CFT has achieved, though.

Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/358864/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/399038/2451 and links therein.

You can see the basic problem already in 2D geometry. If you conformally compactify the hyperbolic plane, you get the Poincaré disk, which has a circle of points at infinity (in higher dimensions, a (hyper)sphere). If you conformally compactify the Euclidean plane, you get the Riemann sphere, which has a single point at infinity (in higher dimensions, still a single point). The elliptic plane is already compact and no points at infinity can be added. So only in the hyperbolic case does there seem to be a hope of having a nontrivial theory on the conformal boundary.
When you add a time dimension, things get more complicated:
Conformally compactifying AdSn+1 gets you what amounts to the direct product of the Poincaré disk and a circle, because time in AdS is cyclic. If you "unwrap" the time dimension after compactification by taking the universal cover, you get $B^n\times\mathbb R$, whose boundary is $S^{n-1}\times\mathbb R$, with the $\mathbb R$ direction being timelike. So there is a chance of a bulk theory in the interior of $B^n$ and a boundary theory evolving together in time and being dual to one another.
Conformally compactifying dSn+1 gets you a space whose boundary is two $n$-spheres at past and future temporal infinity. They are spacelike, so there is no time evolution on the boundary. If you try to put some kind of theory (i.e., constraint) on the boundary, you are just constraining the initial and final conditions of the universe.
Conformally compactified Minkowski space has three points/singularities* at spatial infinity and past and future temporal infinity, and two $S^{n-1}\times\mathbb R$ surfaces at past and future null infinity. While the $S^{n-1}\times\mathbb R$ in compactified AdS has signature $+{-}\cdots-$ or $-{+}\cdots+$ depending on convention, the $S^{n-1}\times\mathbb R$s in compactified Minkowski space have signature $0{-}\cdots-$ or $0{+}\cdots+$, and also, there are two of them. It's not obvious to me that those differences would prevent you from concocting some sort of boundary holography for Minkowski space, but it's a different problem, and apparently a more difficult one.
* Per this answer, n+1-dimensional Minkowski space can be seen as having a dSn at spatial infinity, but I think you would have to abandon conformality to use it for holography purposes.
Of Minkowski holography, Prahar said in a comment on this question:

Previous attempts attempted to mimic AdS/CFT and used $i^0$ [spatial infinity] as the appropriate boundary, but they all mostly failed. Recent attempts (Celestial Holography and/or Carrollian Holography) use $\mathcal I$ [null infinity] and that seems to have had more success. Nothing has yet come close to what AdS/CFT has achieved, though.


So does this mean that the conjecture is "merely" a consequence of the toy model and that it does not translate to "real physics"?

@FlatterMann There are other reasons than AdS/CFT to believe in gravitational holography, and the idea predates AdS/CFT. I'd guess that some form of gravitational holography is valid in a $Λ>0$ universe even if it doesn't look like AdS/CFT.

Thanks! I appreciate the perspective.
